# What is the proper way to await for async inside of a ForEach?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

.NET Core 2.2, VS 2019

The problem is, the `UpdateDatabaseWithFile` is never getting executed?  What am I doing wrong here?   I tried to wrap `Directory` with an await, but I can't, since it returns void.  What is the proper way to do this?

Here is the code:

```
Directory
   .GetFiles(@"C:\Temp")
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(async file =>
   {
        await this._dataService.UpdateDatabaseWithFile();
   });
```

Comment: If `UpdateDatabaseWithFile()` never gets executed, then the implication is that the list is empty. What makes you think it's not getting executed?

Comment: What is the value of `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp").ToList()` ?

Comment: By the way,m do you want to execute  `UpdateDatabaseWithFile` sequentally? Or it is ok if operations will be executed parallely?

Comment: I know the UpdateDatabaseWithFile is not getting executed, because the code inside of it never executes.
I would prefer they run in parallel, it's a matter of efficiency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because `ForEach<T>` just executes that `async` functions, but didn't wait for their completion.

You can use `Select` for projecting `Task`s which has to be executed and then use  `Task.WhenAll()` to execute that functions and wait for their completion:

```
 var tasks = Directory
        .GetFiles(@"C:\Temp")
        .Select(async file =>
        {
            await this._dataService.UpdateDatabaseWithFile();
        });


 await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or if you want to execute functions sequentally, then instead of `Task.WhenAll()` you can use simple `foreach`:

```
 foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp"))
 {
      await this._dataService.UpdateDatabaseWithFile();
 }
```

Additional explanation:

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,34f9a4f31a6489c8) is the implementation of `ForEach<T>`:

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < array.Length; i++) {
       action(array[i]);
  }
```

As you see it just executes that action but didn't wait for their completion. And actually, it can't. `Action` returns nothing. But for waiting `Task` has to be returned. So, for making `ForEach` function useful in that situation, it has to take `Func` which return `Task` and then await inside `for` iterator..

Comment: I can't do var tasks = Directory.   I get an error saying I can't assign 'void'.

Comment: @BrianKitt May be you didnt change ForEach to Select?

Comment: @BrianKitt Have you solved the problem? Interesting to me whether my answer was useful for you or not

Comment: I did miss the 'SELECT', and that did fix my problem.   Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

The method [`List.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) doesn't understand async delegates, in other words it hasn't an overload that accepts a `Func<Task<T>>` parameter. In these cases what happens is that the supplied async lambda is treated as `async void`. [Async voids are evil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), because they can't be awaited, so their execution can't be coordinated with other parts of the program. They are similar to fire-and-forget tasks, with the added drawback of killing the process in case of an exception.

> Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make asynchronous event handlers possible.

You should pay attention to the signature of the method you are attempting to call with an async delegate as argument. Some methods like [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) have specific overloads for async delegates, and handle them well. Other methods like the LINQ [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) are not designed with async await in mind, but at least they accept arguments of type `Func` instead of `Action`, and so the generated tasks are returned and can be collected and awaited properly. Methods like the `List.ForEach` with `Action` arguments should never be used with async delegates.

Answer (score -2):

The most likely problem here is that `.ForEach()` provides no way for you to actually wait for the operations to complete. It will just execute them and move on.

Eric Lippert has [a good blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) on why the `.ForEach()` method isn't all that great, and this is a perfect example of how a `foreach` loop excels over `.ForEach` - `foreach` will allow you to actually await the operations.

Just use a loop, and your problems go away:

```
foreach (var file = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp"))
{
    await this._dataService.UpdateDatabaseWithFile();
}
```

It should be noted that you don't seem to actually be using the `file` variable anywhere, and that seems like a problem. Hopefully just a typo?

Comment: this is not an answer to his question, although I definitely agree with you, I think you should use a comment..

Comment: @ChristopheDebove A very likely cause of OP's issue is that `.ForEach` is creating a fire-and-forget situation with no way to await the operations' completion. If that is indeed the issue, then using a `foreach` loop solves that. I believe what I have put here may well solve OP's issue and that would mean that it is an answer. I realize it was a bit lacking as far as explanation goes so I have added some clarification.